# Error about JSON while Using sklearn_porter

Tags: scikit-learn

I trained a SVC model with SKLearn for Python. I have to save it (and SKLearn do not have an included solution for this) and then use it in JavaScript, on client side, so I checked my options :

- joblib.dump then using Pyodide (so I can use my libs as SKLearn)
- m2cgen that export the model and its functions in a JS file
- sklearn_porter, that do the same, but seems to be unsupported

I tried these options, nothing goes on.

###### for Pyodide :

I'm following instructions on [getting started guide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/quickstart.html), here is the exemple code :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/pyodide/v0.23.2/full/pyodide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Pyodide test page <br>
    Open your browser console to see Pyodide output
    <script type="text/javascript">
      async function main(){
        let pyodide = await loadPyodide();
        console.log(pyodide.runPython(`
            import sys
            sys.version
        `));
        pyodide.runPython("print(1 + 2)");
      }
      main();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

but there is this error

> Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

and I don't want to try to change the call stack limite, as I saw the result with m2cgen

###### for m2cgen :

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

So I tried a brutal solution : `sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)`. Not only is it not working, but also it made crash VSC. Of course, it was obviously a stupid method, but I'm on my personal PC, so I can try things. But there is no way I give it a try on a browser, potentially on someone else device (so Pyodide = out)

###### for sklearn-porter :

Finally, I'd to try this solution... but after I finally agreed to downgrade SKLearn from 1.2.2 to 0.22 (2019, december, latest version working with sklearn-porter) I'm struggling with the error :

> TypeError: JSONDecoder.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Even if I'm not trying to use sklearn_porter functions. Only including this `from sklearn_porter import port, save` is generating this error. Do you have an idea of the issue ?

Here is a working Python script, before trying to export the model

```py
"""Imports-------------------------------------------------------"""
# Outils
import json
import sys
# from joblib import dump

# SKLearn
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
# from sklearn_porter import port, save
"""Fonctions-----------------------------------------------------"""
def loadDataset():
    try:
        with open("datasetFull.json") as file:
            datasetFull = json.load(file)
            return datasetFull
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

"""Script--------------------------------------------------------"""
print("Initialisation du script d'entraînement...")
dataset = None
try:
    dataset = datasets.load.iris()
except Exception as e:
    print("Une erreur s'est produite lors du chargement du dataset :", str(e))
    sys.exit()

X = dataset.data
Y = dataset.targer
N = len(X)

XTrain, XTest, YTrain, YTest = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.8, stratify=Y)
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(XTrain)
XTrainStd = sc.transform(XTrain)
XTestStd = sc.transform(XTest)

svc = SVC(C=1.0, random_state=1, kernel="linear")
svc.fit(XTrainStd, YTrain)

YPredict = svc.predict(XTestStd)
bonnesPredictions = 0
nPredictions = len(YPredict)
for i in range(len(YPredict)):
    if YPredict[i] == YTest[i]:
        bonnesPredictions += 1
print("Accuracy score : %d / %d = %.2f" % (bonnesPredictions, nPredictions, bonnesPredictions / nPredictions))
```